# Retrieving all network requests required to load a webpage using python

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests

Let say I am making a python request

```py
url = "https://www.google.com"
r = requests.get(url)
```

Is there any method for getting all the network requests needed to load such a website, for example, those listed in the inspect element tool in chrome? I believe that I could achieve the same effect using Selenium, but is there any library or method that I could use to simply get all the network requests/network responses when requesting a URL.

Comment: you would have to get HTML and search all url for images, JS, CSS and other files. And later you would have to read CSS and search all URL, and you would have to load JS and search URL - but JS may generate URLs so it may not work. So it needs to Web Engine like in real browser - and Selenium gives you real browser but I don't know if it gives access to requests. OR maybe you should check Web Widget like in PyQt which can load page and you may assign events to run own function

Comment: https://zetcode.com/python/requests/

Answer (score 0):

Selenium Wire may be worth a try. I haven't been able to find much else in this space either.

---

https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire

Selenium Wire extends Selenium's Python bindings to give you access to the underlying requests made by the browser. You author your code in the same way as you do with Selenium, but you get extra APIs for inspecting requests and responses and making changes to them on the fly.

---

This article describes more HTTP Request packages that may have similar capabilities or related extensions.

https://www.twilio.com/blog/5-ways-http-requests-python